# Get values "0" and "1" alternated rows on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2015, I have a table with a list of values "name", my necessity is to add a column that alternate values "0" and "1" when the "name" columns changes. This is important for me because, I import this query on excel, and I will format the rows with conditional formatting reading the value of "trig". This is an example of desidered result.

```
+-----+--------+
| trig|  name  |
|-----+--------|
|  0  |  0400  |
|  0  |  0400  |
|  1  |  0150  |
|  1  |  0150  |
|  1  |  0150  |
|  0  |  0111  |
|  0  |  0111  |
+-----+--------+
```

Thank you

Comment: can you share original data and then expected result in a table, does the order of name column always remain same ? or can it change

Comment: how the column order is decided ? do we have any other id column or date column ?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2015** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `DENSE_RANK` here:

```sql
SELECT name, (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) - 1) % 2 AS trig
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The logic here is that `DENSE_RANK` will return a value, starting with 1, for each group of name records.  We can take the mod 2 of this value to obtain 0 or 1 alternatively for each name.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
name,
case when name = (lead(name) over(partition by name)) then 0 else 1 end as trig
from [table name]
```

if the case when doesn't work directly then use cte:

```
with data as (

select 
name,
lead(name) over(partition by name) as next_row
from [table name]
)

select
name,
case when name = next_row then 0 else 1 end as trig
from data
```

Answer (score 0):

i used row_number:

```
with data as(
select
name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order BY name ) 
    AS Row#
from [table name]
group by name
)
select 
t.name,
row#,
(row#-1)%2 trig
from [table name] t
left join data d
on t.name = d.name
order by name
```